# show custom text field only when it's populated

Tags: product-attribute, magento-1, product-view

Having trouble with a custom field. It's a plain text field, called special_note.

```
<?php $specnote = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('special_note');
  if ($specnote) {
    echo "<div id='specialnote'>".$specnote->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)."</div>";
  }
?>
```

The specialnote div is always showing up, even when there's data. I've tried variations like `if (!empty($specnote))` and `if (!isnull($specnote))` to no avail.

How do I make is so that the div only shows up when it's been populated?

Additional info: this is in the file /app/design/frontend/mytheme/theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Field is set up in magento as a 'text field' - and the settings "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" and "Used in Product Listing" are both set to yes.

Comment: Isn't this a liitle overhead? Why don't you use `$_product->getSpecialNote()`?

Comment: It weirdly returns a blank space. like if I do `<?php echo "<div>".$_product->getSpecialNote()."</div>" ?>` - I get `<div> </div>` as a result.

Comment: getSpecialNote was completely not returning anything for a while - reindex, then clear cache (the full cache storage), in that order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$specnote = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('special_note');
```

Does not return the result you are expecting.
That code, returns an instance of the product attribute `special_note` If the attribute exists or an empty instance of a product attribute if the attribute does not exist. So if you use the result in an `if` statement it will always evaluate to `true`.
Try using this code:

```
<?php $specnote = trim($_product->getSpecialNote());?>
  if ($specnote) {
    echo "<div id='specialnote'>".$specnote."</div>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Ah. That info makes a lot of sense. However, your code returns a blank space, literally `<div id='specialnote'> </div>`. Some I'm wondering if I did something else incorrectly.

Comment: As I noted above, if I do `<?php echo "<div>".$_product->getSpecialNote()."</div>" ?>` - I get `<div> </div>` - so getSpecialNote doesn't work at all, and I have no idea why that is.

Comment: @SamC. I changed something. Try now. I added a trim

Comment: Still nothing. I'm certain the field is set up right (added notes to my original Q about the config). Should I not have used the word 'special' or something?

Comment: OH, scratch that. Must remember to dump caches between major edits. Also, minor typo - remove the `?>` at the end of the the first line.